# Как вызвать форму обратной связи после ввода слова в поле?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var message = document.getElementById("message"),
  insert = document.getElementById("code"),
  code = new Array();

function capture() {
  debugger;
  cmd = insert.value;
  insert.value = "";
  switch (cmd) {
    case "feedback":
      /* Код, что после ввода слова feedback должна всплывать форма обратной связи*/
      break;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content" onclick="document.getElementById('code').focus();">
    <ul id="message"></ul>
    <input type="text" onkeyup="Latin(this);" onKeyPress="if(event.keyCode==1 3) capture(); " id="code " />
  </div>
</section>
<div id="contactable "></div>
```

id="contactable" — форма обратной связи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var message = document.getElementById("message"),
  insert = document.getElementById("code"),
  code = new Array();

function capture() {
  cmd = insert.value;
  insert.value = "";
  switch (cmd) {
    case "feedback":
      const example = document.getElementById('contactable')
      example.style.display = 'block'
      break;
  }
  return false;
}

insert.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  if (e.target.value === 'feedback') {
    const example = document.getElementById('contactable')
    example.style.display = 'block'
  }
})
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content">
    <ul id="message"></ul>
    <input type="text" id="code" />
  </div>
</section>
<div id="contactable" style="display: none;">Example</div>
```

Под себя подредактируйте, эвенты надо вешать через `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

Набери в поле слово "da"

```js
var contactable = document.getElementById("contactable");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (input.value === 'da') {
    contactable.classList.add('contactable');
  }
})
```

```css
#contactable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#contactable.contactable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<div id="contactable"></div>
```